# Adding a carriage return on Comment in data driven subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report subscription in Excel render format, and I need to a multiple comments line.  How to I add a carriage return to make the text in the 2nd line.  I know in SSRS it is VBCRLF.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but I don't see how you would be able to specify a return in that text box. How about creating a field that has a CHR(10) in your data driven query and *Get the Value from the Database*?

Comment: In SSRS you can me the text go at the bottom by using VBCRLF and change the type to HTML. I need to know in data driven subscription comment box if there's such syntax similar to vbcrlf that can be use to make the next line of text go on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Comment is HTML enabled so you can simply use `<br />`. This relies on the client email service to render, but that isn't an issue in most cases. Just keep in mind that if you use more advanced HTML it may render differently in different mail programs.

Comment: So for the comment box for example I would type the text like: Text1 <br/> Text2 <br/>.  This is how it looks like after I went back and edit the data driven subscription: TEST1 &lt;br/&gt; test2 &lt;br/&gt;

Comment: Add a column to your query that has `'Text1 <br/> Text2'` then use the "Get the Value from the Database" option to use this new column for the comment.